# Why "else" doesnt work in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I started learning Python yesterday and I'm having a problem when using the `if` condition. Even if the mean of all the numbers is lower than 6, the program prints `"mean"`.

```
cali = 0
calificaciones_uriel = []


print "to exit enter a negative number"

while cali >=0:
    cali = float(raw_input("give me the numbers: "))
    if cali > 0:
        calificaciones_uriel.append(cali)

suma = 0

for cal in calificaciones_uriel:
    suma = suma + cal


if str(suma / len(calificaciones_uriel)) > float(6):
    print "mean: "+ str(suma / len(calificaciones_uriel))
else:
    print "not enough"+ str(suma / len(calificaciones_uriel))
```

Comment: Why are you converting `suma / en(calificaciones_uriel)` to a printable string with `str`, and then comparing the string with `6` as a float? that doesn't make much sense, does it? Leave the `str` off when doing the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have added type conversions where they are not necessary, in an attempt to fix this problem. Change your code to:

```
if suma / len(calificaciones_uriel) > 6:
```